# Sqlserver Database with Space in Name

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a sql server database through the SqlcConnection class in c#.  I have noticed that any database with a space in the name, I cannot connect to.  From previous questions on this website I have tried the following:

- Enclose name in []
- Enclose name in {}
- Enclose name in ``

It does not seem to work.  Here is my connection string code:

```
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=" + Settings.settings.sqlUserName + ";" +
                  "pwd=" + Settings.settings.sqlPassword + ";server=" + Settings.settings.sqlServer + ";" +
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                  "database=" + "'" +  Settings.settings.databaseName + "'" +  "; " +
                  "connection timeout=10");
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `user id` and `pwd` here? They are ignored with `Trusted_Connection=yes`.

Comment: Good question, I do need a user and password though to be able to connect to the server.  I'll disable it and see if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding brackets [] do work, my problem was that the application that creates the database automatically removes the spaces, thus the reason why I could not connect to it!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the brackets, this worked for me:

```
Before:
string connStr = @"Data Source=yyy;Initial Catalog=[space prob];Integrated Security=SSPI;";

After:
string connStr = @"Data Source=yyy;Initial Catalog=space prob;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```